# Redis : 'appenddirname' param gives 'Bad directive or wrong number of arguments'

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

**Goal** - To be able to write the redis data (which is .aof/.rdb) files to the file system mount location below.

**I am following this doc** : https://redis.io/docs/management/config-file/

I am on kubernetes pod for redis server , Redis version v=6.0.8 ( using open source version of redis not enterprise)

My Redis config file content is :

```
cluster-enabled no
cluster-config-file nodes.conf
cluster-node-timeout 5000
appendonly yes
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
appenddirname "/mount/redis-data"
appendfsync everysec
aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync yes
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb
aof-load-truncated yes
```

and then I am creating the redis cluster with the ip's set

```
redis-cli .. --cluster create  .. --cluster-yes
```

That's when I get the following error :

```
*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR (Redis 6.0.x) ***
Reading the configuration file, at line x
>>> 'appenddirname "/mount/redis-data"
Bad directive or wrong number of arguments
```

Answer (score 1):

`appenddirname` is a new feature of Redis 7.0, i.e. multi-part AOF files. Since you're using older version, you cannot set this configuration, and you only need to set `appendfilename`.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I tried using path with the mount location but I got the following message. 

*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR (Redis 6.0.8) ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 8
>>> 'appendfilename "/mount/redis-data/appendonly.aof"'
appendfilename can't be a path, just a filename

So how can I achieve my goal, which is to write the redis data (in AOF or RDB file format) to the desired file system mount location ? . Is there any other alternative way ?

Comment: With older version Redis, you cannot config a path. In order to put those files in the desired mount location, you can switch (cd) to the location, and run redis-server. AOF file will be saved at the current working directory.

Comment: Thanks, so is there no other alternative way besides the redis.conf file , like so bulk export or some redis-cli command to do this for current version of redis ? also what all different options do I have to do the needful ?